# TYPO3 setup issue with Composer + Distribution Package + helhum/typo3-secure-web

Tags: docker, composer-php, typo3-9.x, ddev

We are facing an issue with distribution package composer. Our goal is to achieve DDEV + Composer + Distribution Package + helhum/typo3-secure-web (thx a ton @helhum for such great security solution).

**Problem/Issue**

When trying to access backend then it does not work, Check this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JwvY.png with CSS/JS is not accessible, seems some directory structure (private/public) cause issue.

**Setup Approach**

Step 1: Create a project's folder

```
mkdir my-typo3-site
cd my-typo3-site
```

Step 2: Configure PHP version

```
ddev config --project-type php --php-version 7.2
```

Step 3: Setup TYPO3 latest version

```
ddev composer create typo3/cms-base-distribution ^9 --no-interaction
ddev config --project-type typo3
ddev start
```

Step 5: Composer.json, Setup private and public folders

```
"extra": {
   "typo3/cms": {
       "root-dir": "private",
       "web-dir": "public"
   }
}
```

Step 4: Secure your TYPO3 with folder structure private and public

```
ddev composer require helhum/typo3-secure-web
```

Step 5: Create FIRST_INSTALL file

```
touch private/FIRST_INSTALL
```

Step 6: TYPO3 Installation Wizard (successfully)

**Composer**

The composer code which is generated by typo3/cms-base-distribution ^9

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^5.5.5",
        "typo3/minimal": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^9.5",
        "helhum/typo3-secure-web": "^0.2.8"
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "root-dir": "private",
            "web-dir": "public"
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes**

Everything works well with ddev composer require typo3/minimal:^9 It only causes an issue with distribution package.

What could be a problem with the distribution package? I would appreciate your feedback. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Is the problem just that cookies aren't enabled in your browser? That's what the screenshot is saying. I don't think you can do any login-based activity without cookies enabled...

Comment: I've already cross-verified and cookies are already enabled. A major issue that, CSS/JS path seems not working (mapping issue with private and public folders). Maybe some confliction with helhum/typo3-secure-web (because that's doing changes of public/private folders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hurray, just resolved the issue! It's just a matter of changing/following orders as follows:

```
Step 1: Create a project's folder
Step 2: Configure PHP version
Step 3: Composer distribution package
Step 4: Create FIRST_INSTALL file
Step 5: TYPO3 Installation Wizard
Step 6: Composer.json, Setup private and public folders
Step 7: Secure your TYPO3 with folder structure private and public
Step 7: ddev composer require helhum/typo3-secure-web
```

Hurray! Once again, Thanks @Helhum for such great secure TYPO3 solution :)

## InspirePeopleToSecure

Cheers,

Sanjay

Comment: So the key is to `composer require helhum/typo3-secure-web` *after* everything else is set up... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's true! I've also talked with @Helhum for the same :)